# css: Image won't resize

Tags: html, css

I've been searching for an answer but I just can't find one...
Basically, I'm trying to put in some images that will act as preview images for a link; the images and link appear via a javascript command executed when an icon is pressed. However, for some reason, the image just won't resize, no matter what I try doing. I've tried to look up for a solution, but nothing is working for some reason. Here's the relevant code:

```css
    html.body {
    height: 100%;
}

.sectionbox {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.bigiconlinkbox_above {
    background-image: url('/images/bg1_top.png');
    background-position: bottom;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
}
.bigiconlinkbox {
    background-image: url('/images/bg1_mid.png');
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 64px;
}
.bigiconlinkbox_below {
    background-image: url('/images/bg1_bot.png');
    background-position: top;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
}

.bigiconlink {
    display: inline-block;
    float: initial;
    margin: 2px 16px;
}

#js_target1 {
    /*text-align: right !important;*/
}
#js_target2 {
    /*text-align: right !important;
    */
}
.descimageholder {
    /*text-align: right !important;
    */
    width: 64px;
    height: auto;
}

.descimage {
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
```

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pictures";
}
<div class="sectionbox">
    <div class="bigiconlinkbox_above">
        <h2>Pictures</h2></br>
    </div>
    <div class="bigiconlinkbox">
        <div class="bigiconlink">
            <a href="" id="js_link1"><img src="~/images/a.gif" alt="a" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bigiconlink">
            <a href="" id="js_link2"><img src="~/images/b.gif" alt="b" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bigiconlinkbox_below">
        <div id="js_target1">Title</div></br>
        <div id="js_target2">Click on an icon for a description.</div>
        <div id="js_target3" class="descimageholder">s</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('js_link1').onclick = showDesc1;
    function showDesc1() {
        document.getElementById("js_target1").innerHTML = "<a href=\"(some url)</a>";
        document.getElementById("js_target2").innerHTML = "description";
        document.getElementById("js_target3").innerHTML = "<img class=\"descimage\" src=\"/images/c.png\" />";
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('js_link2').onclick = showDesc2;
    function showDesc2() {
        document.getElementById("js_target1").innerHTML = "b";
        document.getElementById("js_target2").innerHTML = "description";
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Note that I need to finish this by New Year's Day.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can please clarify what does what, and how to reproduce the issue.  looking at your snippet it's hard to tell what I'm supposed to click and where the image issue lies.  it would also be great if you can update the snippet with working image links

Comment: At least 1 thing is broken: `"<a href=\"(some url)</a>";` but not sure if that's because you stripped your example or not. In general I advise to not use backslash escaping, just mix single quotes with double quotes so you don't go insane over missing 1 escape.

Answer (score -1):

From your questions above, I hope I understand it well. Here is a script I use to preview profile pictures.

```
<img src='url_here' height=51 width=50 style='border-radius: 5px;'>
```

I hope this is the answer for your question. It resizes the picture as a thumbnail or preview. You may change the height and width according to the size you need.